# What type of Ping is this?

Tags: identification, plant-care, carnivorous-plants

I got this ping/butterwort as a present. (If you're wondering why it has no flower, I accidentally knocked off its stem/flower.)

The instructions for caring for a ping vary depending on which variety it is, so I'm hoping someone can identify what variety of ping this is. [image]

If you have any advice about how to care for this plant, that would be welcome also!

Comment: I can take more detailed pictures if you can describe what you would need to help identify it.